# Adding groupby min / max / count aggregations

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I have following pandas dataframe.

```
 ex_one  ex_two weight  fake_date
0  228055  231908      1 2004-12-17
1  228056  228899      1 2000-02-26
2  228050  230029      1 2003-01-27
3  228055  230564      1 2001-07-25
4  228059  230548      1 2002-05-04
```

Here is what I want:

from column `ex_one` take for an example `228055` and then count number of occurrences based on `fake_date` (`max`) and `fake_date`(`min`) value for `228055`

```
 ex_one  ex_two weight  fake_date      max_date     min_date   frequency             
0  228055  231908      1 2004-12-17   2004-12-17   2001-07-25  2
1  228056  228899      1 2000-02-26
2  228050  230029      1 2003-01-27
3  228055  230564      1 2001-07-25
4  228059  230548      1 2002-05-04
```

Comment: In your original df, index 3 has ex_one=228059. In the output, it changes to 228055. How?

Comment: oh sorry, this was just a sample I wanted to use. I changed it manually. There are over 100 counts on each of values in ex_one. That as done for demonostration purposes only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one way.

```
df['fake_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['fake_date'])

g = df.groupby('ex_one')['fake_date'].agg(['min', 'max', 'count']).reset_index()

res = df.merge(g, how='left')
```

**Result**

```
   ex_one  ex_two  weight  fake_date        min        max  count
0  228055  231908       1 2004-12-17 2004-12-17 2004-12-17      1
1  228056  228899       1 2000-02-26 2000-02-26 2000-02-26      1
2  228050  230029       1 2003-01-27 2003-01-27 2003-01-27      1
3  228059  230564       1 2001-07-25 2001-07-25 2002-05-04      2
4  228059  230548       1 2002-05-04 2001-07-25 2002-05-04      2
```

**Explanation**

- Caste `fake_date` column as `datetime` type if not already done.
- Create a `groupby` dataframe with your 3 aggregations.
- Left merge with original dataframe.